# Drag&drop between listboxes which are classes in a collection

Tags: vba, class, collections, drag-and-drop

Being a self-taught VBA programmer I usually search the internet until I find a satisfactory solution for the problems (and the limitations of VBA) I stumble upon. I do not simply copy code of others, I really try to understand it as well, so I can learn from it. Long story short: I used code I found for dragging data from one listbox to another. Originally, the code (for 2 listboxes) was simply put in the form's code module but I wanted to use it in a class module so I don't have to copy/paste the same code for each and every d&d listbox I use on a form. The code I use:

(Code module of the form; just the listbox part)

```
Option Explicit
Private collection_ListBox As New collection
Private collection_ComboBox As New collection
Private collection_Textbox As New collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim frm_control  As Control

Set collection_ListBox = New collection
Set collection_ComboBox = New collection
Set collection_Textbox = New collection

For Each frm_control In Me.Controls

    Select Case TypeName(frm_control)

        Case "ListBox"

            Dim obj As CfrwxDragDropList: Set obj = New CfrwxDragDropList
            Set obj.FRWX_Control = frm_control: obj.Initialize
            collection_ListBox.Add obj

        Case "ComboBox"

        Case "TextBox"

    End Select

Next frm_control

'***TEMP for testing purposes***
ListBox1.List = Array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7")

End Sub
```

(Code module of the class)

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents FRWX_DragDrop As msforms.ListBox
Private Item_Source As msforms.ListBox

Public Property Get FRWX_Control() As msforms.ListBox

Set FRWX_Control = FRWX_DragDrop
End Property

Public Property Set FRWX_Control(reg_Control As msforms.ListBox)

Set FRWX_DragDrop = reg_Control
End Property

Public Sub Initialize()

'Nothing here yet!

End Sub

Private Sub FRWX_DragDrop_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

If FRWX_Control.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
If Button = 1 Then

    Call SetDraggedItem(FRWX_Control)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub FRWX_DragDrop_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As msforms.ReturnBoolean, _
ByVal Data As msforms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, _
ByVal DragState As Long, ByVal Effect As msforms.ReturnEffect, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)

Cancel = True
Effect = fmDropEffectMove
End Sub

 Private Sub FRWX_DragDrop_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As msforms.ReturnBoolean, _
ByVal Action As msforms.fmAction, _
ByVal Data As msforms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, _
ByVal Effect As msforms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Cancel = True
Effect = fmDropEffectMove

Call AddDroppedItem(FRWX_Control, Data, Y)
Call DeleteDraggedItem(Item_Source)
End Sub

Private Sub SetDraggedItem(lb As msforms.ListBox)

Set Item_Source = lb

Dim dataObj As New DataObject
dataObj.SetText lb.Text
Call dataObj.StartDrag(fmDropEffectMove)
End Sub

Private Sub AddDroppedItem(lb As msforms.ListBox, dataObj As DataObject, Y As Single)

lb.AddItem dataObj.GetText, FixDropIndex(lb, Y)
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteDraggedItem(lb As msforms.ListBox)

Dim selIndex As Long

With lb

    selIndex = .ListIndex
    .Selected(selIndex) = False
    .RemoveItem selIndex
End With

Set Item_Source = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function FixDropIndex(lb As msforms.ListBox, Y As Single) As Long

Dim toIndex As Long

With lb

    toIndex = .TopIndex + Int(Y * 0.85 / .Font.Size)

    If toIndex < 0 Then toIndex = 0
    If toIndex >= .ListCount Then toIndex = .ListCount
End With

FixDropIndex = toIndex
End Function
```

So far so good; everything works fine except for one tiny little thing: I get an error on

```
Call DeleteDraggedItem(Item_Source)
```

in the sub FRWX_DragDrop_BeforeDropOrPaste. I know WHY I get this error: when I drop the DataObject in ListBox2, Item_Source in the corresponding instance of the class will be empty for it was filled in the ListBox1 instance of the class. So I need a way to let ListBox2 know the source of the dropped text. I can think of 2 ways of fixing this.

1. The first one sends shivers down my spine only thinking of it, for it feels almost like blasphemy: I could send it with the DataObject along with the text itself by 'expanding' lb.Text with "|" followed by lb.Name and split the string in the receiving instance. It will work, but I don't like this kind of solutions.
2. I could pass the name of the source ListBox to the parent (being the form itself) from instance 1, so instance 2 can ask for it there. I haven't tried that solution yet, but I'm sure I'll get it to work.

So now for my questions: 
1. is solution 2 a/the right way to go?
2. are there other/better solutions I haven't thought of yet?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

***** UPDATE *****
As mentioned below, I found another (I think better) fix myself. The events are still triggered from the class instances for each listbox, but I used a separate, single instance of a class that performs the actual actions attached to them. Here's the updated code:

(Code module of the form; just the listbox part)

```
Option Explicit
Private collection_ListBox As New collection
Private collection_ComboBox As New collection
Private collection_Textbox As New collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim frm_control  As Control

Set collection_ListBox = New collection
Set collection_ComboBox = New collection
Set collection_Textbox = New collection

 Dim handler As CfrwxDragDropList_EventHandler: Set handler = New CfrwxDragDropList_EventHandler

For Each frm_control In Me.Controls

    Select Case TypeName(frm_control)

        Case "ListBox"

            Dim obj As CfrwxDragDropList: Set obj = New CfrwxDragDropList
            Set obj.FRWX_Control = frm_control: obj.Initialize
            Set obj.FRWX_EventHandler = handler

            collection_ListBox.Add obj

        Case "ComboBox"

        Case "TextBox"

    End Select

Next frm_control

'***TEMP for testing purposes***
ListBox1.List = Array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7")

End Sub
```

(Code module of the listbox class "CfrwxDragDropList"

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents FRWX_DragDrop As MSForms.ListBox
Private FRWX_DragDrop_Handler As CfrwxDragDropList_EventHandler
Private Item_Source As MSForms.ListBox

Public Property Get FRWX_Control() As MSForms.ListBox

Set FRWX_Control = FRWX_DragDrop
End Property

Public Property Set FRWX_Control(reg_Control As MSForms.ListBox)

Set FRWX_DragDrop = reg_Control
End Property

Public Property Get FRWX_EventHandler() As CfrwxDragDropList_EventHandler

Set FRWX_EventHandler = FRWX_DragDrop_Handler
End Property

Public Property Set FRWX_EventHandler(handler As CfrwxDragDropList_EventHandler)

Set FRWX_DragDrop_Handler = handler
End Property

Public Sub Initialize()

'Nothing here yet!

End Sub

Private Sub FRWX_DragDrop_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

If FRWX_Control.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
If Button = 1 Then

    Call FRWX_DragDrop_Handler.SetDraggedItem(FRWX_Control)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub FRWX_DragDrop_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, _
ByVal DragState As Long, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)

Cancel = True
Effect = fmDropEffectMove
End Sub

Private Sub FRWX_DragDrop_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, _
ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, _
ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Cancel = True
Effect = fmDropEffectMove

Call FRWX_DragDrop_Handler.AddDroppedItem(FRWX_Control, Data, Y)
Call FRWX_DragDrop_Handler.DeleteDraggedItem
End Sub
```

(Code module of the eventhandler class "CfrwxDragDropList_EventHandler"

```
Option Explicit
Private Item_Source As MSForms.ListBox

Public Sub SetDraggedItem(lb As MSForms.ListBox)

Set Item_Source = lb

Dim dataObj As New DataObject
dataObj.SetText lb.Text
Call dataObj.StartDrag(fmDropEffectMove)
End Sub

Public Sub AddDroppedItem(lb As MSForms.ListBox, dataObj As DataObject, Y As Single)

lb.AddItem dataObj.GetText, FixDropIndex(lb, Y)
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteDraggedItem()

Dim selIndex As Long

With Item_Source

    selIndex = .ListIndex
    .Selected(selIndex) = False
    .RemoveItem selIndex
End With

Set Item_Source = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function FixDropIndex(lb As MSForms.ListBox, Y As Single) As Long

Dim toIndex As Long

With lb

    toIndex = .TopIndex + Int(Y * 0.85 / .Font.Size)

    If toIndex < 0 Then toIndex = 0
    If toIndex >= .ListCount Then toIndex = .ListCount
End With

FixDropIndex = toIndex
End Function
```

That's it! It works between 2 listboxes, but if you want to use more it'll work as well. You can move items between listboxes, but also change the order of items within a listbox.

Comment: So, `"everything works fine"` -- except for the fact that *it doesn't work?*  :)  Your option #2 sounds like it's straightforward.  If you can get it to work then you should do it, because if not, the other optoins are only going to get more complicated.

Comment: Well, it DOES work if you want to _copy_ data from one listbox to another or within a listbox... ;-) If there are other options, I don't mind they get more complicated if they are _better_ / _more professional_ solutions. For example, I read something about a wrapper class for the event handlers, but I couldn't get my head around it. Myabe you could shine some light on that?

Comment: Fixed it! I went along with the idea of a separate eventhandler class and suddenly I saw the light (hallelujah!). I updated the original post, hopefully my solution is helpful to others. Still, if someone has a better solution I'd be glad to hear it. For now, this works fine for me.